On Schauder estimates and harmonic coordinates in Petersen's book
In Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry(3rd ed), Section 11.2, following form of local Schauder estimate is stated without proof (Theorem 11.2.2):
For elliptic 2nd order differential operator $L$ on bounded domain $\Omega$ with $K\subset\subset\Omega$, we have
$$||u||_{C^{2,\alpha},K}\le C\left(||Lu||_{C^{\alpha},\Omega}+||u||_{C^{\alpha},\Omega}\right)$$
and
$$||u||_{C^{1,\alpha},K}\le C\left(||Lu||_{C^{0},\Omega}+||u||_{C^{\alpha},\Omega}\right)$$
First I believe that the $||u||_{C^{\alpha},\Omega}$ term on the right hand sides should be $||u||_{C^{0},\Omega}$ (which is in the standard form of Schauder estimate). But where can I find the proof of the second statement which says that gradient of $u$ can be bounded by $C^{0}$ norm of $Lu$ and $u$? Is it possibly a typo? If it is true then is there a global estimate of similar form?
Also in the following discussion the author proves the existence of harmonic coordinates, Lemma 11.2.5. In the proof he argues that for a normal coordinates $y$ we have $\Delta y=0$ at $0$ hence we have $||\Delta y||_{C^{\alpha},B(0,\varepsilon)}\rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. However $\Delta y=0$ at $0$ only implies $||\Delta y||_{C^{0},B(0,\varepsilon)}\rightarrow 0$ so I think we need to use the global version of the second statement above (indeed we only need to control gradient). Thus I'd like to know whether it is indeed true and what I think is correct.
